# How to use condition inside another condition in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, cakephp

I have one field answer. Also I have two ids i.e men and women id fields name as `ca_field_id` in another table.

My requirement is I want to get data with following conditions

1. with both ids men(id=37) and women(id=38)
2. age of men 67
3. age of women 65

But I am getting data of both i.e men with 67 age as well as women with 67 age and vice versa.

With below query:

```
$numberofemployeesmen = 37;
$numberofemployeeswomen =38;

$caanswer = $this->CaAnswer->find('all', 
    array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'CaAnswer.ca_field_id' => array($numberofemployeesmen,$numberofemployeeswomen),
            'CaAnswer.answer' => array(67,65)
         )
     )
 );
```

Also I tried as following but did not work

```
$numberofemployeesmen = 37;
$numberofemployeeswomen =38;

$caanswer = $this->CaAnswer->find('all', 
    array('conditions' => array(
        'CaAnswer.ca_field_id' => array($numberofemployeesmen,$numberofemployeeswomen),
        'CaAnswer.answer'=> array(
            67 AND array('CaAnswer.ca_field_id' =>$numberofemployeesmen),
            65 AND array('CaAnswer.ca_field_id'=>$numberofemployeeswomen))
        )
    )
 );
```

Please tell how I can solve this...

Comment: Please indent code by 4 spaces or by selecting it and pressing ctrl+K. Inline code should be marked like this: `\`code\`` Thanks.

Comment: Which field stores the age?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$numberofemployeesmen = 37;
$numberofemployeeswomen = 38;

$caanswer = $this->CaAnswer->find('all', 
    [
        'conditions' => [
            'OR' => [
                [
                    'CaAnswer.ca_field_id' => $numberofemployeesmen,
                    'CaAnswer.answer' => 67
                ],
                [
                    'CaAnswer.ca_field_id' => $numberofemployeeswomen,
                    'CaAnswer.answer' => 65
                ],
             ]
         ]
     ]
 );
```

If that doesn't work, you might need to add additional `AND` keys within the `OR`:

```
$caanswer = $this->CaAnswer->find('all', 
    [
        'conditions' => [
            'OR' => [
                [
                    'AND' => [
                        'CaAnswer.ca_field_id' => $numberofemployeesmen,
                        'CaAnswer.answer' => 67
                    ],
                ],
                [
                    'AND' => [
                        'CaAnswer.ca_field_id' => $numberofemployeeswomen,
                        'CaAnswer.answer' => 65
                    ],
                ],
             ]
         ]
     ]
 );
```

Notice in this one, the `AND` are within an array of their own so the second `AND` key doesn't overwrite the first.

The idea is that you're saying I want either this first set of AND conditions OR the second set of AND conditions. But within each, both conditions need met.

It might not be exactly right, but these should give you the idea of how it can be done. (Just going off the top of my head).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
$caanswer = $this->CaAnswer->find('all', 
    array('conditions' => array(
        'CaAnswer.ca_field_id' => array($numberofemployeesmen,$numberofemployeeswomen),
        'CaAnswer.answer'=> array(
            67 AND array('CaAnswer.ca_field_id' =>0),
            65 AND array('CaAnswer.ca_field_id'=>1))
        )
    )
 );
```

If I am not mistaken array($numberofemployeesmen,$numberofemployeeswomen) creates an array like this 0=>$numberofemployeesmen 1=>$numberofemployeeswomen